# Object not found error with aes and shiny

Tags: r, shiny, ggtern

I would like to create a ternary plot dashboard using Shiny. But I am stuck in this error. This code takes a CSV file and updates the three drop-down input. Then the ternary plot created has upon these three drop-down values. The problem is I keep getting an error from "aes" function that tells me the object "x_s" is not found.
this is my code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

    plotOutput("ggtern"),
    
    fileInput("csv_file", "source", multiple = FALSE, accept = "csv",
              width = NULL, buttonLabel = "Browse...",
              placeholder = "No file selected"),
    
    selectInput("x_val", "Choose x values:", choices=c()),
    selectInput("y_val", "Choose y values:", choices=c()),
    selectInput("z_val", "Choose z values:", choices=c()),
    )
    
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    selectedData <- reactive({
        inFile <- input$csv_file
        if (is.null(inFile))
            return(NULL)
        df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath,na.strings = c("", "NA", "#N/A"))
        updateSelectInput(session,"x_val","x series",colnames(df))
        updateSelectInput(session,"y_val","y series",colnames(df))
        updateSelectInput(session,"z_val","z series",colnames(df))
        return(df)
        })
    
    T1 <- reactive({
        if (is.null(selectedData()))
            return(NULL)
        temp <- selectedData()[input$x_val]
        return (unlist(temp))
    })
    
    T2 <- reactive({
        if (is.null(selectedData()))
            return(NULL)
        temp <- selectedData()[input$y_val]
        return (unlist(temp))
    })
    
    T3 <- reactive({
        if (is.null(selectedData()))
            return(NULL)
        temp <- selectedData()[input$z_val]
        return (unlist(temp))
    })
    
    output$ggtern <- renderPlot({
        if (is.null(selectedData()))
            return(NULL)
        x_s <- T1()
        y_s <- T2()
        z_s <- T3()
        vec <- aes(x_s,y_s,z_s)
        obj <- ggtern(data=selectedData(), vec)
        print(obj)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have tried many other ways to implement this but every time I get this same error.

Comment: Try `aes_string` instead of `aes`.

Comment: Many thanks, yes it works, but I get some other error when adding geom_point() to the obj. **CoordTern requires the following missing aesthetics (tlr->xy) : z**